# Minimum code for graphics?

Tags: java, graphics, jframe

What is the absolutism minimum code I can use to gave a `JFrame` with `Graphics` ? ,so for example can i get rid of the `paint()` method ? , do I need to call `super.update(g)` ?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What is the motivation behind your restriction?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am just looking for the best way to draw graphics ...

Comment: @ExotickBoyPl Maybe Cairo, or OpenGL. Or both: http://cairographics.org/OpenGL/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not override paint(). That is generally for AWT.

You should not touch update(). Again that is for AWT.

In Swing you override the `paintComponent()` method of a `JPanel` (or `JComponent`) and add the panel to the frame.

You don't touch the `JFrame` at all.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

the paint() method is still available for overriding in JFrame. A better solution would be to add a small class that extends JPanel and overrides the " paintComponent(Graphics g) " method to serve as a canvas for your shapes to be drawn on. You would then just add that panel in as another component in your JFrame. and inorder to update the contents you can call the repaint() method.
for example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class DoNotEnterSign extends JPanel {
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Point center = new Point(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
    int radius = Math.min(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2) - 5;
    int innerRadius = (int)(radius * 0.9);
    int barWidth = (int)(innerRadius * 1.4);
    int barHeight = (int)(innerRadius * 0.35);
    g.fillRect(center.x - barWidth/2, center.y - barHeight/2,
               barWidth, barHeight);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("A simple graphics program");
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new DoNotEnterSign();
    panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN.darker());
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}}
```

this the basic components of a Swing class. Although there can be simpler solutions.
now you maynot have to update() things, for example if u have a textarea  where you can enter a text and a button to convert to Upper case then

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                area.setText(area.getText().toUpperCase());
```

would update itself as soon as it finds the setTextarea()